# Дана символьная строка. Если символ повторяется, нужно второе его вхождение заменить на 2, третье на 3 и т.д. Написала так, но работает неправильно

Tags: python

> Дана символьная строка.
>  Если символ повторяется, нужно:
>
> - второе его вхождение заменить на 2,
> - третье на 3,
> - и т.д.

Написала так, но работает неправильно.

**Например**, строку `abcebdkbf` он заменяет на `a2ce2dkbf`.
Т.е он заменяет все только на 2 и заменяет первое вхождение, при этом не трогает последнее.

```
s = input()
n = len(s)
for i in range(n):
    k = 1
    for j in range(i+1, n):
        if s[i] == s[j]:
            k += 1
            if k > 1:
                T = str(k)
                s = s.replace(s[j], T, 1)
print(s)
```

Comment: Неправильно -- это как? Добавляйте подробностей, пожалуйста

Comment: Например, строку abcebdkbf он заменяет на a2ce2dkbf.

Comment: Т.е он заменяет все только на 2 и заменяет первое вхождение, при этом не трогает последнее.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь лучше использовать словарь

```
s = input()

d, out = {}, ''
for char in s:
    if d.get(char): #если очередной символ уже есть в словаре (ранее встретился в тексте)
        d[char] += 1 # инкрементируем счетчик этих символов
        out += str(d[char]) # добавляем в результирующую строку значение повторений символа вместо самого символа
    else: # если символ еще не встречался, вносим его в словарь с числом повторений 1
        d[char] = 1
        out += char # в выходную строку добавляем символ - он встретился первый раз
print(out)
```

```
длинношеее
длин2оше23
```

Без словаря

```
s = input()
out = ''
for i, char in enumerate(s): # перебираем символы в строке: i - индекс символа в строке, char - символ
    k = s[:i].count(char)  # считаем кол-во таких символов в срезе от начала строки до (не включая) позиции этого символа
    if k:  # если k>0, т.е. этот символ встретился в срезе слева
        out += str(k + 1)  # добавляем в результирующую строку значение повторений символа вместо самого символа
    else:
        out += char  # в выходную строку добавляем сам символ - он встретился первый раз
print(out)
```

Comment: А возможно ли написать код, работая только со строками? (требование преподавателя к заданию)

Comment: Добавил способ без словаря

Comment: @gggrwson - Добро пожаловать на  Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)